# How to mock autowired beans in a spock test meant for a service?

Tags: spring, unit-testing, grails, spock

I need to inject a bean into a service for a test to work. I have this service class:

```
class ContentService {

    @Autowired
    Evaluator evaluator

    ... 

}
```

When run its unit-test counterpart, it fails by saying that it cannot find a bean that matches a good candidate for the `Evaluator` bean. My understanding is that Grails manages to automatically instantiate the service variable for you but here it seems it lacks some information to build it properly. That would be the test:

```
@TestFor(ContentService)
class ContentServiceSpec extends Specification {

    def setup() {
        evaluator = Mock(Evaluator)
        service.evaluator = evaluator
    }

    def "Should test..."() {
       ...
    }

}
```

It seems it is too late to mock the `experimentEvaluator` and inject it manually in the test in the `setup()` method, as it fails with:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [ExperimentEvaluator] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1301)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1047)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533)
    ... 28 more
```

I've seen some references to `defineBeans` around although it seems it's not used anymore in 2.5.0. I cannot understand how to use it as it is not explained in the Grails test documentation nor in the API documentation.

I've also seen `doWithSpring` but same story: I have no idea how to use it getting past the normal usage, whereas I need to create a mock for it.

I use Grails 2.5.0. I am new to Grails and I am lost in some of its magic.

Comment: How does `Evaluator` and `ExperimentEvaluator` look like?

Comment: Sorry I re-edited my answer but Evaluator and ExperimentEvaluator are the same. This code is from a proprietary code base so I cannot simply dump it here. The `Evaluator` class is Java and has no empty constructor. It is not something easy to instantiate and it would be easier to mock it and inject it in the service (+ being in the spirit of unit-testing :) ).

Answer (score 3):

You should use doWithSpring to add a mocked instance of your dependency by using `org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.InstanceFactoryBean`.

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.InstanceFactoryBean

@TestFor(ContentService)
class ContentServiceSpec extends Specification {

    static doWithSpring = {
        evaluator(InstanceFactoryBean, Mock(Evaluator), Evaluator)
    }



    def "Should test..."() {
       ...
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using `doWithSpring` as shown below in the spec?

```
import grails.test.mixin.support.GrailsUnitTestMixin

@TestMixin(GrailsUnitTestMixin)
@TestFor(ContentService)
class ContentServiceSpec extends Specification {

    static doWithSpring = {
        evaluator(Evaluator)
    }

    def setup() {
        service.evaluator = evaluator
    }

    def "Should test..."() {
       ...
    }

}
```

Refer [doWithSpring and doWithConfig callback methods, FreshRuntime annotation](http://docs.grails.org/3.0.9/guide/testing.html) for details ([original link](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.5.0/guide/testing.html) no longer active; new link refers to Grails 3.x but is still relevant for dowithspring notation).

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes I've tried, but problems are that a) there is no Evaluator bean for Spring to find anywhere but even then, b) I want to mock the Evaluator. How can I mock the Evaluator and tell Spring to use it in the service instantiated by the Spock unit-test?

Comment: If `Evaluator` is not a bean then how is it `@Autowired` in the first place inside `ContentService`

Comment: It must be a bean declared somewhere but I cannot find where it is defined. My reasons for believing so is that it is already used in another class / test and those work without a hitch for both test and runtime. That other class though is not a service and hence does not make use of the `@TestFor` annotation along with the spock unit-test automatic instantiation of the `service` object. 

If I replace `@TestFor` with `@TestMixin` and manually instantiate the service and inject the bean, it works good. So that's my work around for the time being.

Comment: If you can come up with a sample app in github replicating this problem, I will be glad to help you out.

Comment: Thanks @dmahapatro for looking into this. As I found a workaround (i.e. to remove the `@TestFor` annotation and manage the dependency injection myself), it would be too much time spent on the job for this issue if I build a sample app in github. I will get myself more familiar over time with the existing application I work with too so maybe I will revisit my question later. Thanks again for your time!